# Best way to do this - Email

Tags: email, wordpress, html-email, email-analytics

We use a wordpress plugin to build our newsletter. We compile specific wordpress posts to send out to our staff. Once compiled we send the newsletter to our listserve which then the email gets approved and sent out to our 1000 staff.

We would like a way to track the emails to see how many read it or what post gets the most readibility. These stats will help us to improve our newsletter to fit the needs of our staff.

The plugin we use does track stats but once the email hits the listserve it stops the count and just shows 1 email out.

Does anyone know of a better plugin or way to track our emails with??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tracking email bounces, opens, clicks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973143/tracking-email-bounces-opens-clicks)

Comment: Also [Mass email tracking](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1219590)

Comment: Also [Track mass email campaigns](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2958926) and many more. Googling or searching Stack Overflow for `track email` will give a lot of good hits.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending the link of the post in email , then add one more parameter to it.. and check that parameter on post template load..

Then store the post ID into db table (fields: post_id, visit_count).. then from next visit just update the counter, so that you can achieve or track the most read posts from email.

Comment: I sorta understand what you are saying sandip.  I am sorta new to mysql and php but I will see what I can do. Thank you for your reply and help.